# Using IFELSE for data generation from multiple Probabilities

Tags: r

Im writing some code in R whereby i need to generate a data set from specific criteria given they meet certain conditions.

I have three probabilities
A - 0.423, B - 0.324 and C- 0.253.

I want to run a random generated sample `runif(50, 0, 1)`.

If the number generated lies between 0 and 0.423, i want to generate a value from `rnorm(50, 25, 4)`,
if its between 0.423 and 0.747, i want to generate a value from `rnorm(50, 28, 4.5)`
and finally if its between 0.747 and 1, i want to generate a value from `rnorm(50, 30, 5)`.

I was trying to do this using some sort of compound `ifelse` function but to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Cheers

Comment: A combination of `findInterval` and `switch` should suffice

Comment: Cute, although I think @DavidRobinson's answer is probably more beginner-friendly. OP: can you replace your title with something more specific/informative?

Comment: Actually, @mnel, I'm not sure that `findInterval` and `switch` *will* work.  `switch` is not vectorized ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you suspected, this can be done using `ifelse`:

```
u = runif(50, 0, 1)
values = ifelse(u < .423, rnorm(50, 25, 4),
                ifelse(u < .747, rnorm(50, 28, 4.5),
                       rnorm(50, 30, 5)))
```

This works because `ifelse` can operate along vectors.

You might prefer this method, especially if you end up having more than three sections to break it into:

```
means = c(25, 28, 30)
vars = c(4, 4.5, 5)
probs = c(.423, .324, .253)
samples = sample(1:3, 50, replace=TRUE, prob=probs)
values = rnorm(50, means[samples], vars[samples])
```

Comment: Lets say there was a fourth probability that necessitated utilising the following: 0.335 < u < 0.512. What would be the most efficient way of dealing with this. im guessing just an extra line with ifelse(0.335 < u < 0.512, rnorm(50, X, Y).  Thank you for the prompt answer.

Comment: You would just add another nested `ifelse` (it may be helpful to work through the logic of the answer one step at a time to understand what it's doing; then the extension to four categories rather than three might be more obvious to you).

Comment: @user1642166: Please look at my latest edit. It is nicely extendable to any number of means and variances.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Thanks for that addition. Very helpful. Just to clarify, this addition you made is doing the same thing with the probabilties and the ranges for the allocation of the rnorm(50, X, Y)?

Comment: @user1642166: Yes, it does the same thing. Note that the probabilities are the differences between the numbers you gave (could be generated as `diff(c(0, .423, .747, 1))`)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of  `switch`, `findInterval` and either `do.call` or `mapply`.

Which you use may depend on how you want the output sorted

### set up switch

```
A <- 0.423
B <- 0.324
C <- 0.253
interval <- c(0, cumsum(c(A, B, C)))
random <- runif(50, 0, 1)

rnorm_vals <- function(interval) {
    switch(interval, `1` = list(mean = 25, sd = 4), `2` = list(mean = 25, sd = 4.5), 
        `3` = list(mean = 30, sd = 5))


}

intervals <- findInterval(random, interval, rightmost.closed = T, all.inside = T)



how_many <- table(intervals)

rnorm_calls <- lapply(names(how_many), function(nm) {
    do.call(rnorm, c(n = how_many[[nm]], rnorm_vals(nm)))
})
rnorm_calls

## [[1]]
##  [1] 28.38 18.54 20.52 25.79 27.50 36.86 23.40 20.82 23.75 30.64 27.62
## [12] 20.23 24.21 22.21 20.16 21.73 29.96 27.28 25.68
## 
## [[2]]
##  [1] 24.91 30.90 30.35 26.08 18.74 27.33 23.29 33.80 30.37 27.49 36.78
## [12] 23.03 24.66 21.46 22.62 33.32 16.16
## 
## [[3]]
##  [1] 30.62 29.50 31.19 25.07 24.68 33.25 40.04 33.42 30.81 21.48 32.79
## [12] 25.56 30.98 30.16
## 


# or (will be sorted by )
unlist(rnorm_calls)

##  [1] 28.38 18.54 20.52 25.79 27.50 36.86 23.40 20.82 23.75 30.64 27.62
## [12] 20.23 24.21 22.21 20.16 21.73 29.96 27.28 25.68 24.91 30.90 30.35
## [23] 26.08 18.74 27.33 23.29 33.80 30.37 27.49 36.78 23.03 24.66 21.46
## [34] 22.62 33.32 16.16 30.62 29.50 31.19 25.07 24.68 33.25 40.04 33.42
## [45] 30.81 21.48 32.79 25.56 30.98 30.16
```

### using mapply

or you could sweep through and get single calls to rnorm

```
rnorm_details <- lapply(intervals, rnorm_vals)
means <- sapply(rnorm_details, `[[`, "mean")
sds <- sapply(rnorm_details, `[[`, "sd")

mapply(rnorm, n = 1, sd = sds, mean = means)

##  [1] 24.70 24.33 36.22 21.87 25.40 18.39 23.54 26.90 25.81 17.35 19.45
## [12] 18.53 33.88 27.51 21.70 25.06 24.17 35.08 28.24 21.88 29.90 28.18
## [23] 29.08 24.54 30.43 29.27 28.79 22.09 20.77 18.82 21.73 22.99 26.69
## [34] 27.73 26.66 25.32 29.95 30.77 34.89 28.55 22.95 32.45 36.11 29.72
## [45] 39.23 22.39 26.78 23.36 18.06 33.39
```